# Throttle the servers upload speed per user using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a situation where I need to be able to throttle / limit the upload speed (outgoing server connection) for each of my users using PHP. The reason why is because I'm running a small streaming website for my family and friends and currently each user can download data from the server at the users highest possible speed which causes other users to suffer due to lack of bandwidth on my server.

I did some calculations and I noticed that **each user** only need **1 Mbps** to be able to stream movies from my server without any buffering.

**So my question is:**

**How can I throttle / limit the servers upload speed per user using PHP?**

I would be very happy if you could provide an example of how I can accomplish this, as of now I have no idea how i can do this.

Comment: Usually "upload" always refers to the user sending content to the server. You're asking about limiting *download* speed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I did not know that, I thought that we were on the server side and thus upload would mean the user downloading. Found a few topics with your search criteria. Thank you :)

Comment: I know, it does seem a bit weird, but think of it as a river. The source (ie. your server) sends content downstream to the users. Downstream = download, upstream = upload :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle`](https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle)

```
use bandwidthThrottle\BandwidthThrottle;

$in  = fopen(__DIR__ . "/resources/video.mpg", "r");
$out = fopen("php://output", "w");

$throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();
$throttle->setRate(1, BandwidthThrottle::MIBIBYTES); // Set limit to 1MiB/s
$throttle->throttle($out);

stream_copy_to_stream($in, $out);
```

Comment: Does this work per user session and will not affect other simultaneous users?

Comment: The given example affects all users. With `$throttle->setStorage(new SessionStorage())` you can limit per session.